# Extending Django User with subclasses

Tags: python, django

Due to my app requeriments I need an hierachy of users classes like:

```
class CommonUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="profileImages",blank=True,null=True)  
    #HERE: Common properties for every user
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Installer(CommonUser):
    #HERE: Specific properties for Installer Companies


class Administration(CommonUser):
    #HERE: Specific properties for Administration


class Client(CommonUser):
    #HERE: Specific properties for Clients
```

Well, in view.py I need to get the profile image for an user. I get the user by the request, so I have an models.User objects and I dont know to witch class it belong. Im not able to do:

request.user.commonuser.photo

because user object doesnt have any OnetoOne relation with commonuser but with installer/administration/client...

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: One approach can be to create fields for CommonUser like is_administration,is_client,is_installer with default value False and set them to true when you create the object of that type.

Comment: You probably want to think of these things as Profile rather than User.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on mobile, so I can't test this, but...

I would set a "related_name" on your CommonUser.user field called "commonuser". Then you can just use:

```
request.user.commonuser.photo
```

like you are already.

I think the issue is that you are referencing a Django User object to reference a backwards relationship without the proper name.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think this model is more of a Profile than User.  If you don't mind using 1.9 (and postgres) then this is a perfect usecase for a JSON field.  You can filter with regular lookups and don't need to specify each type.  That way you can also extend the user model in such a way that a user can fulfill many roles at once.  The other thing I thought of was linking it the other way around:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...

class Installer(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='installer')
    #HERE: Specific properties for Installer Companies


class Administration(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='admin')
    #HERE: Specific properties for Administration


class Client(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='client')
    #HERE: Specific properties for Clients
```